# How can I populate new sheet with each row based on specific account number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel sheet with 10,000 lines, and maybe 800 accounts. My goal is to create a new sheet in the same workbook where I can type in an account number, and it populates with each row from my master sheet, that corresponds that specific account number? One concern of mine, each account will have a different number of rows that correspond.

Comment: Look into Advance Filters

Comment: Advanced filters, PivotTables, and VBA would all work in this context. You may also want to consider going to a different application, like an Access database, which supports this kind of functionality more effectively.